# Google API calls quota for calendar: How can an application be built relying on only 10K calls per day?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I want to make an application that would need to use google calendar api. Now the quota for api calls per day per app is 10K. Is this rational? If my app has as few as 10K users making more than one api call a day, it would ran out of quota. So what can i do to avoid this quota? Or what would be the solution for an app that has much more users and needs more api calls?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is rational. Google has no obligation to give you unlimited (or bulk) usage of their API that they've provided for free for a service that they've provided for free. That said, yes it is possible to get around or increase this limit. This is what [Google](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/pricing) says:

> The Google Calendar API has a courtesy limit of 10,000 queries per day. If you need capacity beyond this courtesy limit, you can send a request from the [Quotas](https://code.google.com/apis/console/#%3aquotas) pane of the Google APIs Console.

Comment: I did see that "Request for more" option. And i understand google has no obligation to give me bulk usage of their api. But why are they providing the api then? If applications having more than a few users cannot use the api, then what's the point of providing it at all? Even if i request and get some extra quota for some time, that cannot be a long time solution for my application!
My questions might sound naive, but i am really confused about that policy.

Comment: I could imagine building out something for small-scale use. Requesting extra quota seems perfectly reasonable as a long-term solution. I'm sure Google is willing to permanently increase the quota for an application which they approve of.